# Production Build Has Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am basically just trying to serve a new ember created project on my production server. After running,

```
ember build --env production
```

And taking the files from dist/assets/ and putting on a page on my server that includes them I get the error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
```

My app is serving basically a blank HTML file with these assets included. The url I am trying to serve from is MyURL/admin.

Comment: Try using the index.html file generated in the dist directory.

Comment: what is your Ember version? and have you upgraded recently?

Comment: Ember version is good Majid. Gaurav, I can get it to work when I use the index.html file as is. The only thing I see special in here is the meta tag. I assume this is required? It does not really cover the generated index.html in the guides.